# php regex preg_match on a variable containing a url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to run a regex on a url to extract all the segments after the host. I can't get it working when the host segment is in a variable and i'm not sure how to get it working

```
// this works
if(preg_match("/^http\:\/\/myhost(\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_\/.]*)$/", $url, $matches)) {
  return $matches[2];
}

// this doesn't work
$siteUrl = "http://myhost";
if(preg_match("/^$siteUrl(\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_\/.]*)$/", $url, $matches)) {
  return $matches[2];
}

// this doesn't work
$siteUrl = preg_quote("http://myhost");
if(preg_match("/^$siteUrl(\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_\/.]*)$/", $url, $matches)) {
  return $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `/` in your variable declaration. One quick fix is to change your regex delimiter from `/` to `#`. **Try**:

```
$siteUrl = "http://myhost";
if(preg_match("#^$siteUrl(\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_\/.]*)$#", $url, $matches)) { //note the hashtags!
  return $matches[2];
}
```

**Or without changing the regex delimiter:**

```
$siteUrl = "http:\/\/myhost"; //note how we escaped the slashes
if(preg_match("/^$siteUrl(\/[a-z0-9A-Z-_\/.]*)$/", $url, $matches)) { //note the hashtags!
  return $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, there is a function called [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). (*Something similar to what you are trying to achieve through your code*).

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```